# How can I create a Dart Function from a String?

Tags: dart

I have a `List<String>` of Dart function names.  For example, `['func1', 'func2', 'func3']`.  I want to call each function in the `List`.  How can I go from a `String` to a `Function`?  The following code does not work, but conceptually it does what I want:

```
var func1 = Function('func1');
```

See how it creates a `Function` from `'func1'`.

Edit: I need to deal with `String`s because I read the list of functions from a file.

Comment: i don't think you can do that in dart, but why not keep a list of functions instead of strings?

Comment: @ViniciusPinto I read the list of function names from a file, so I'm stuck with Strings.

Comment: I’d use a map to associate the strings with the corresponding functions

Comment: @ViniciusPinto if you put this in an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Dart allows that at the moment (for objects you could use [`dart:mirrors`](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/server/reflection-with-mirrors), but it's currently marked as an unstable library).

An alternative is to use a Map to associate the strings with the functions, as in:

```
void foo() {
  print('foo');
}

void bar() {
  print('bar');
}

void main() {

  var functions = {
    'foo': foo,
    'bar': bar
  };

  // calling foo()
  functions['foo']();

  // or
  var b = functions['bar'];
  b();

}
```